# .htaccess file doesn't work properly with path_info and/or get method

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Fixed it. Did a small change on the file. It can be seen below.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

I have been trying for a whole day to fix an issue I'm having. I have this .htaccess file which simply rewrites the urls just like

```
http://example.com/about/?req=true
http://example.com/index.php/about/?req=true
```

It works on my localhost without a problem, but when I upload it to the server I get this "no input file specified" error. You can see the content of the .htaccess file below.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried different things I found on the internet including adding a php.ini file which sets cgi.fix_pathinfo to 1, but none of them worked except one and that one doesn't read the request string. You can see that one below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to rewrite `http://example.com/about/?req=true` to 
`http://example.com/index.php/about/?req=true`? how could a directory beneath a file ever work (even on a locale machine)? Shouldn't it be something like this? `http://example.com/about/index.php?req=true` or like this `http://example.com/index.php?req=true&page=about`?

Comment: @serjoscha i think you got it wrong. what i'm trying to do here is use $_SERVER['path_info'] to handle user friendly urls in a better way.

Answer (score -1):

First off all check whether rewrite module is enable in apache or not 
if enable then u can use this code hide index.php with in url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /base_directory_name/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /base_directory_name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I think this will help u .